# I am using Zegocloud video classes in flutter app and getting this issue java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-run, zegocloud

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libRoomkitDC.so" not found
```

after this error the application closed unexpectedly.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629): Process: com.webbullindia.lms.ssa, PID: 4629
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libRoomkitDC.so" not found
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.zego.roomkitdc.RoomkitDCSDK.init(RoomkitDCSDK.java:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.zego.roomkitdc.RoomkitDCSDK.<init>(RoomkitDCSDK.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.zego.roomkitdc.RoomkitDCSDK.getInstance(RoomkitDCSDK.java:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.zego.roomkitdc.logger.ZegoRoomkitLogger.<init>(ZegoRoomkitLogger.java:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.zego.roomkitdc.logger.ZegoRoomkitLogger.getInstance(ZegoRoomkitLogger.java:2)      
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.Logger.Logger.i(Logger.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.v0.ZLMeetingManager.e(ZLMeetingManager.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.v0.ZLMeetingManager.<init>(ZLMeetingManager.java:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.v0.ZLSDK.b(ZLSDK.java:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.service.ZegoRoomService.<init>(ZegoRoomService.java:456)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.service.ZegoRoomKitCoreManager.<clinit>(ZegoRoomKitCoreManager.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkitcore.service.ZegoRoomKitCoreManager.init(ZegoRoomKitCoreManager.java:1) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at im.zego.roomkit.service.ZegoRoomKit.init(ZegoRoomKit.kt:67)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.lms.students.ssa.RoomKitPlugin.init(RoomKitPlugin.kt:20)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.lms.students.ssa.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:20)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.lms.students.ssa.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$djU0VNIj3E39ONTA0IvnPUW3BfY(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.lms.students.ssa.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)   
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)      
E/AndroidRuntime( 4629):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everything related to issue is mentioned above.

Comment: Can you tell me which document you refer to access the RoomKit SDK?

Answer (score 1):

After getting support from the Zegocloud Team, I got a answer from them i.e.,
Zegocloud Roomkit android SDK currently not support *app-x86 architecture of android apps.